# Authenticated users to site collection unable to open some site settings pages and modify settings

Tags: 2013, authentication, cumulative-update

HI after recent SharePoint 2013 Cumulative updates installed in production farm authenticated users those users are owner permissions in the site collection and site collection administrators not able to change some site settings for example below page.
 but these users do not have SharePoint admin user permissions i.e local administrator in WFE servers.

_layouts/15/AreaTemplateSettings.aspx
_layouts/15/ChangeSiteMasterPage.aspx

https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/praveenh/2013/04/30/intermittent-http-403-forbidden-error-while-trying-to-browse-to-a-sharepoint-web-app/

from the above article, I added permissions on the bin directory for authenticated users.

Comment: Have you checked the ULS logs, may be clue over there? did you add the permission on all WFEs?

Comment: if i make this user local administrator in wfe server he can able to change settings of site

Comment: this is not acceptable, as user does not required admin rights on server...did you run the config wizard after the cu? also check the status of the databases?

Comment: I saw below in ULS log file.
Throttled: Big list slow query. List item query elapsed time: 0 milliseconds, Additional data (if available
System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: The attempted operation is prohibited because it exceeds the list view threshold enforced by the administrator and after i increased list view threshold value for web appicatin

Comment: here in masterpage gallary i found many versions of master pages i will delete those old versions and issue will be solved